# Logging-Strategy (slf4j?) for external libraries

Tags: java, logging, jar, log4j, slf4j

I want to provide a client-library for wrapping rest-request to a server and log errors, so that a client can use it in his app and also see the logs. (There is also a question if i should just log the errors or rethrow it. When i use an asynchronized call (multithreaded) this might be quite tricky..)

I read that slf4j might help, because the client, who is using the library, can choose which logging framework he prefers.

Somethings puzzles me about this slf4j-thing. If he gets my library and i just provide, let's say the slf4j-api, errors will be thrown, cause the SLF4J bindings aren't  included. The solution might be that he has to include the binding on his own, and the question is if he is willing to read the README for this crucial information.

If i include one "standard"-slf4j binding (e.g. the simple one), the app can't "override" this, because there is just one binding allowed on the classpath. It won't be flexible anymoe

So i am thinking to just use log4j and forget every other logging-framework. I may think to complicated on this subject, maybe someone might help me out on this?

Comment: How does your client library look like? Is it one single JAR file containing everything (including the logging framework) or an archive containing your library and its dependencies?

Comment: As of version 1.6.0, if no binding is found on the class path, then SLF4J will default to a no-operation implementation. Thus, slf4j-api by itself with not throw exceptions when no binding is found on the class path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remember, your library does not set the wrapping application's classpath. The wrapping application will set a classpath that includes your library, the slf4j API library and the implementing library.

The wrapping application will take care of what slf4j implementation to use and setup all of the logging parameters. You just need to worry about logging your libraries events with the slf4j API. This is common practice, don't worry about the wrapping application.

By packaging log4j within your library, you are defeating the purpose of a logging facade. Doing so will not allow the user to pick the slf4j implementation.